# My ubuntu starts without unity

Tags: boot, unity, display-manager

When I started Ubuntu this morning the login was different than usual. [image: login screen] The user names were not provided as options, rather I had to type them which was very confusing (I never had to type my username before). Anyway, after I had succeeded in feeling my way through I found the Ubuntu desktop is missing Unity. I tried a couple of things from this site including the following in the terminal.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

It did improve the situation but the top panel was still missing and the improvement didn't survive reboot.
As I am a new user, I am lost. Please help.

Comment: Having no experience with this myself, I might try reinstalling the Unity package, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of that, you had installed `xdm` and then you set it as default display manager.

So you can reconfigure your previous display manager: (for example `lightdm` or `gdm` or ...)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Or if you have `gdm` before:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Or for `sddm`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

And so on ...

Then select your previous display manager in configuration process:
[image: configuration process]

---

Also if you not use `xdm` you can purge it:

```
sudo apt purge xdm
```